# Second time button click is not getting new form fields value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to validate my form fields and showing alert if any of this fields are empty. But after that if user enters the value in that field and than when they click submit button again it keeps showing the error alert even if there are no fields empty anymore.

I have tried following code and found that it works perfectly fine for the first time that is - if there are any empty fields, it will show the error alert. But after that if user enters the value in that field and then again click submit, it's not updating the entered value in jquery and keep showing null value and that is why it's keep showing error alert. I am not able to find any error. Any help would be appreciated. I have tried following code:

```
<form id="desc-form" action="addRecords.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="question-input">
            <textarea required placeholder="Write description here..." name="desc" id="desc" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'desc' );
            </script>

            <select id="select-gender" name="gender">
               // have few options
            </select>

            <input type="radio" name="subscribe" value="1"> Yes
            <input type="radio" name="subscribe" value="2"> No

            <a id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</a>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript>
    $(".btn-submit").click(function() {

        var desc = CKEDITOR.instances['desc'].getData();


    if (desc === "" || $.trim($("#select-gender").val()) === "" || $.trim($('input[name=subscribe]:checked').val()) != 1) {
        alert("Please enter all mandatory details!");
    } else {
        $("#desc-form").submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

So this code is working when there is empty field, but once any value is entered in all the empty field and when the button is clicked again, it still shows the error alert. I know I am missing minor thing, but not getting it. Any help is appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on("click",".btn-submit", function() {
    var text = $(document).find('#desc');
    var radio = $(document).find('input[name="subscribe"]');
    var gender = $(document).find('#select-gender option:selected')
    if(text.val() == "" || radio.is(':checked') == false || gender.val() == 'Select') {
        alert('Please enter all mandatory details!')
    }else{
        alert('submit data')
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="desc-form" action="addRecords.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="question-input">
            <textarea required placeholder="Write description here..." name="desc" id="desc" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
           

            <select id="select-gender" name="gender">
             <option hidden>Select</option>
               <option value="1">MALE</option>
               <option value="2">FEmale</option>
            </select>

            <input type="radio" name="subscribe" value="1"> Yes
            <input type="radio" name="subscribe" value="2"> No

            <a id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</a>
    </div>
</form>
```